# Variation of the contravariant component of the metric respect to the covariant component of the metric

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, metric-tensor, differentiation, variational-calculus

I am recently studying general relativity and it is a bit difficult for me to handle the rise and fall of indices in some calculations. My specific question is how could I find this variation?

$$\frac{(\delta g^{ij} \partial_{i}\phi \ \partial_{j}\phi)}{\delta g_{ij}}$$

My idea was to use this relationship:

$$\delta g^{ij} = - g^{ic}g^{jd}\delta g_{cd}$$

with what I would get this

$$\frac{(\delta g^{ij} \partial_{i}\phi \ \partial_{j}\phi)}{\delta g_{ij}} = g^{ic} g^{jd} \partial_{c}\phi \ \partial_{d}\phi$$

Is this fine?

Comment: Yes. The fast way to get this is to just use $g^{ij}\partial_i \phi \partial_j \phi = g_{ij} \partial^i \phi \partial^j \phi$.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with indices, you have too many contractions of $i$ and $j$ so the Einstein convention does not work here! I think what you want to derive is:
$$
\frac{\delta \left(g^{i j} \partial_{i} \phi \partial_{j} \phi\right)}{\delta g_{ab}}
=\frac{\delta \left(g_{i j} \partial^{i} \phi \partial^{j} \phi\right)}{\delta g_{ab}}=\partial^a\phi \partial^b \phi$$

Whenever you write down an equation, always take a step back and check the indices: here on the left-hand side I only have 2 free indices, $a$ and $b$, all the others are contracted. This is coherent with my final expression where I have two free upper indices, $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 0):

The careful way is to use different indices in the two parts of the derivative, e.g.$$\tfrac{\delta}{\delta g_{ij}}(g_{ab}\partial^a\phi\partial^b\phi)=\color{blue}{\tfrac12(\delta_a^i\delta_b^j+\delta_a^j\delta_b^i)}\partial^a\phi\delta^b\phi=\partial^i\phi\delta^j\phi$$or$$\tfrac{\delta}{\delta g_{ij}}(g^{ab}\partial_a\phi\partial_b\phi)=\color{blue}{\tfrac12(g^{ai}g^{bj}+g^{aj}g^{bi})}\partial_a\phi\delta_b\phi=\partial^i\phi\delta^j\phi.$$In both cases, the blue expression averages two terms because we need to be mindful of both metric tensors being symmetric, so we can't just claim e.g. $\tfrac{\delta}{\delta g_{ij}}g^{ab}=g^{ai}g^{bj}$.